# XNA find out what's taking up so much memory?

Tags: c#, xna

The CLRProfiler doesn't seem to work on any xna games and always waits at.

Waiting for application to start common language runtime

Is there anything else (free) I can use?

Comment: Why in the world the close vote?  He wants to profile an XNA game, it seems like a reasonable question to me although perhaps it belongs on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: What version of the CLRProfiler are you using? CLRProfiler4 works great for me with my XNA projects.

Comment: If you have a memory problem in an xna game, the most likely reason is that you have some loadcontent operations in your update or draw functions, witch consume much memory..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using PIX.  Here is a tutorial by [Matt Pettineo](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/samples-tutorials-tools/pix-with-xna-tutorial/).

Also, there is a [presentation](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3369) by Microsoft.